# Arrow function scope vs regular function scope

Tags: javascript

I've read about the difference between **arrow function** and **regular function** in Javascript so I've made a little node.js demo project to understand what I've learned.

```
let name = 'file Scope'

class User {
   name = "Class Scope"
   arrow = () => {
       console.log("Arrow name " + this.name);
   }
   normal() {
       console.log("Normal name " + this.name);
   }
   test() {
       return {
           name: "Object Scope",
           n: this.normal,
           a: this.arrow,
           nested: {
               name: 'Nested Object Scope',
               nestedNormal: function () {
                   console.log("Nested Normal " + this.name);
               },
               nestedArrow: () => {
                   console.log("Nested Arrow " + this.name);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
let user = new User();

user.test().n(); //Normal name Object Scope
user.test().a();//Arrow name Class Scope
user.test().nested.nestedNormal();//Nested Normal Nested Object Scope
user.test().nested.nestedArrow();//Nested Arrow Class Scope
```

The console output wasn't expected, I thought the **nestedArrow()** function would return **Object Scope** but it returned **Class Scope** otherwise.

Why did "this.name" refer to the name in class and not to the name inside of the nested object?

Comment: `this` is bound to what it was at the time the function was declared. You declare it in the method `test()` of the `user` instance. It takes *that* `this`.

Comment: [Useful read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412087/deeply-self-reference-an-objects-properties) - generally `this` when used in an object initialiser will *not* refer to the object that is currently being initialised but the context where the object is being initialised.

Comment: Also, you seem to be confusing "scope" and "context". Scope is how variables are being looked up, while *context* is the value of `this`. The two are not related to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow function is declared inside the `test()` function so it gets the value of `this` from that function.

You called `user.test()` so inside `test` the value of `this` is the same as the value of `user`.

`user.name` is `"Class Scope"`.

Further reading: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers).